# No error showing on console, still CardELement is not rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Coding a project using React. It's been 3 days I've looking for a solution. I had been learning coding and trying to integrate stripe payment option on my web-app. However, unable to get the proper result. Searched a lot, found no solution.

Code is below :

App.js

```js
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Payment from './Payment';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';


const promise = loadStripe("pk_test_51KtYdQSJwVy1hdNxUPD5HK8KcKbLDVSic6q6jfdPxuSLYiCjuwzBfE8Eo5u0zVclLgPP33InVTjAyM4rZP3ouWB9009AL3lsZ6");


function App() {
  const [{ }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      console.log("THE USER IS >>>>> ", authUser);
      if (authUser) {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser
        });
      }
      else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null
        })
      }
    })
  }, []);


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        {console.log("load stripe>>>>>>>>",promise)}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/payment" element={
            <Elements stripe={promise}>
              <Payment />
            </Elements>
          } />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component in which using Stripe and CardElement (Payment.js) :

```js
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import "./Payment.css";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

function Payment() {
    const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const [error,setError]=useState(null);
    const [disabled,setDisabled]=useState(true);
    const [succeeded,setSucceeded]=useState(false);
    const [processing,setProcessing]=useState("");

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        //do all the stripe stuff
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    const handleChange = event =>{
        // Listen for changes in the CardElement
        // and display any errors as the customer types card details
        setDisabled(event.empty);
        setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
    }

    return (
        <div className="payment">
            <div className="payment__container">
                <h1>
                    Checkout ({<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>})
                </h1>
                {/* Payment section - delivery address */}
                <div className="payment__section">
                    <div className="payment__title">
                        <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="payment__address">
                        <p>{user?.email}</p>
                        <p>786 Chaurangi Marg</p>
                        <p>Delhi, India</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* Payment section - Review items */}
                <div className="payment__section">
                    <div className="payment__title">
                        <h3>Review Items and Delivery</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="payment__items">
                        {basket.map(item =>
                            <CheckoutProduct
                                id={item.id}
                                title={item.title}
                                price={item.price}
                                rating={item.raing} />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* Payment section - payment method */}
                <div className="payment__section">
                    <div className="payment__title">
                        <h3>Payment Method</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="payment__details">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            {/*<CardElement />*/}
                            <div className="card__element">
                            <CardElement />
                            </div>

                            <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                                <CurrencyFormat
                                    renderText={(value)=>(
                                        <>
                                            <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>  
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                    decimalScale={2}
                                    value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                                    displayType={"text"}
                                    thousandSeparator={true}
                                    prefix={"₹"}
                                />
                                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                                        <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            {error && <div>{error}</div> }
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Payment;
```

Comment: Can you please tell what's the error you are getting after form submission ??

Comment: form submission is not my concern. <CardElement /> in payment.js not rendering, that's primary issue

Comment: please try these steps
1) <Route path="/payment" element={ <Payment />} />
2) In <Payment /> component  write 
        <Elements stripe={promise}>
          <AddStripePayment/>
        </Elements>
3) in  <AddStripePayment/> component
    <form>  <CardElement> </form>

Comment: Already tried this. Not worked. Please tell some other solutions. Kind of stuck building project. Causing delay.

Comment: is /payment payment page loading properly? without any error.

Comment: yes, payment component is loading properly without throwing an error